# Extract JSON value in Bash

Tags: regex, bash, macos

In the Bash I saved response data into a variable.

The result looks like this:

```
{"token_type":"Bearer","access_token":"022-8baa5324-f57b-445d-c5ec-821c63a5fd35","expires_in":3600,"scope":"any-website.com"}
```

Now I want to extract the value of the access token into an other var.

In Linux I solved that in this way and it works:

```
echo "$response_json" | grep -oP '(?<="access_token":")[^"]*'
```

As result I get:

```
022-8baa5324-f57b-445d-c5ec-821c63a5fd35
```

My problem is that MacOS does not support the grep parameter `P` (Perl expression) anymore. Parameter `E` does not work with that expression.

I would appreciate any help with a solution without requiring to install additional Bash tools.

Answer (score 2):

Everyone says they don't want to install new tools, but really, line-oriented tools like `grep` simply weren't designed to cope with structured text like JSON. If you are going to work with JSON, get tools designed to process it.

[`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is one such option:

```
$ echo "$response_json" | jq -r '.access_token'
022-8baa5324-f57b-445d-c5ec-821c63a5fd35
```